# Checkboxes in PySide using for loop connects unexpected on stateChanged

Tags: python, python-3.x, checkbox, pyside, qcheckbox

What I'm trying to do is to create checkboxes using for loop and connect a function to them ,which is called with different argument for every checkbox.

Here is some code:

```
for video in videos:
    video_cb = QtGui.QCheckBox(video['title'])
    video_cb.toggle()
    video_cb.stateChanged.connect(lambda: self._toggle_video_cb(video))
    videos_checkboxes_container.addWidget(video_cb)
```

and _toggle_video_cb function:

```
def _toggle_video_cb(self, video):
    print(video['title'])
    video['is_for_download'] = not video['is_for_download']
```

Here `video` is a dictionary whith keys: title: (str) , is_for_download: (boolean)...

The `print` is just for checking the argument and it is the same for every checkbox.No matter which checkbox I click it gives me it prints the same video title.

Why is that so? Is that the right way to do it?

Thanks in advance !

Best regards :)

Comment: I know...but how can i fix that ?

Comment: There are multiple solutions in that question. I would probably go for partial from functools. As suggested from one of the newer answers there.